# P2P instant messaging through NAT

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, p2p

I am trying to set up a P2P instant messaging system, and while I haven't hit the issue yet, I expect I will have some issues if the client is behind NAT on a local LAN (read: Everyone.)

Let me explain the algorithm and you'll see what I mean. There are three components: A server and two clients - Client Alice wants to initiate a chat with Client Bob. The server only keeps track of who is online, but the actual conversation doesn't go through the server (for privacy for the clients)

So, Alice and Bob both sign in to the server - Connecting to the server's static listening port from an ephemeral port. They tell the server what static port they are listening on for incoming chat requests. Alice asks the server how she can contact Bob. The server responds with the ipaddress and listening port, among other things. Alice sends the request to Bob on that IP address and port to establish the connection. Hope that makes sense.

If Bob is behind NAT, then sure he can talk to the server because he's the one who starts the communication. But Alice's request won't get to him because the NAT relationship hasn't been set up yet for the port he's listening on for chat requests, from Alice's IPaddress.

Is there some kind of black magic that someone knows to make this work? Will it be a non issue? Development isn't that far along, I haven't actually hit this problem yet.

To state the obvious, I don't want to have to make end users configure port forwarding for their listening ports.

For the aforementioned black magic, client and server are both in java, but I'm just generally after the algorithm (and if it's even possible)

Comment: Just look at chat systems such at jabber or even skype. You either have to configure port forwarding, use a proxy or a commonly open fallback port like 80 ...

Answer (score 1):

Check [ICE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Connectivity_Establishment).

Most P2P frameworks, like JXTA in Java, use the principle of *relay* servers.

Say A wants to connect to B and B is behind a firewall.

```
- both A and B establish ** outbound ** synchronous (or full duplex/websockets) connections to Relay Server R
- A signals to R that it wants to transmit data to B
- R 'binds' the inbound connection from A to the outbound connection to B (the synchronous HTTP response to B for instance)
- A sends data to R which is relayed to B
```

The key thing here is that all connections are established **outbound** (an usually using a *friendly* firewall protocol like HTTP on well known ports)

Things get obviously a bit more involved when you have distributed relays; you then need 'routers' that maintain routes to various peers via the relays which rely on Distributed Hashmaps (DHTs) to maintain the information.

Answer (score 0):

There is no black magic. If both clients are behind NAT the message has to go through a third party (the server). 
And I would consider using such architecture for all communication if it's only about text messages (you can think of some kind of encryption if privacy is an issue). The server (or servers) will be more loaded but you get simpler (and in some cases more reliable) architecture. For instance, if Alice sends message to Bob, and Bob has some network issues, the server can queue and keep the message for some time and deliver it later (even if Alice goes offline). Another thing is conference (group) chat. Handling it with P2P only is much more challenging (but can be very interesting). But if all clients are behind NAT you get the same problem.
I would also strongly suggest implementing an application-level acknowledgment mechanism for all transmitted and received messages (both from client and server). Protocols such as TCP/IP are not reliable enough.